How to find rows in table per group that are not in another group of the same table
I have a table of products which lists all the products held within our branches. This includes whether a product is a PackingLine one. A product either is or is not a PackingLine, it doesn't change per branch, however not all branches have every packing line. I need to find those branches and products.  A simplified version would be



Branch
FullDesc
PackingLine




1
Prod A
1


1
Prod B
0


2
Prod B
0


2
Prod C
0


3
Prod D
1



I need to select all rows where a branch doesn't have a item that is marked as a packing line inside another branch. i.e. in the example above I would expect



Branch
FullDesc




1
Prod D


2
Prod A


2
Prod D


3
Prod A



As Prod A and D are packing lines and Branch 2 has neither and Branch 1 and 3 has one the other doesn't
My original thought was to create a cte to get a distinct list of Packing Lines (excl. branch) and check for Non-Exists,
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT FullDesc FROM products.Product WHERE PackingRobotLine = 1
)
  SELECT Branch, FullDesc FROM products.Product WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT FullDesc FROM cte 
         WHERE products.Product.FullDesc = cte.FullDesc)

but this of course returns all rows not in the cte including ones that are not PackingLine ones.
What would be the correct way to obtain the required rows.

Here's how we can structure the SQL query to achieve this:

Create a list of all packing line products using a common table expression (CTE).
Use a CROSS JOIN to get all combinations of branches and packing line products.
Use a LEFT JOIN to find the branches that do not have the packing line products.
Filter out the branches that are missing the packing line products.

Here's the SQL query:
WITH PackingLines AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT FullDesc
    FROM products
    WHERE PackingLine = 1
),
BranchProductCombinations AS (
    SELECT b.Branch, p.FullDesc
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Branch FROM products) b
    CROSS JOIN PackingLines p
),
MissingPackingLines AS (
    SELECT bpc.Branch, bpc.FullDesc
    FROM BranchProductCombinations bpc
    LEFT JOIN products pp 
    ON bpc.Branch = pp.Branch AND bpc.FullDesc = pp.FullDesc
    WHERE pp.FullDesc IS NULL
)
SELECT Branch, FullDesc
FROM MissingPackingLines
ORDER BY Branch, FullDesc;

You can get the required output with the above query as shown below:



Branch
FullDesc




1
Prod D


2
Prod A


2
Prod D


3
Prod A



You can check the Fiddle.

You can compare the table on itself to get the elements that are not contained in it:
DECLARE @T TABLE (Branch INT, FullDesc NVARCHAR(MAX), PackingLine INT)
INSERT INTO @T (Branch, FullDesc, PackingLine) VALUES (1, 'Prod A', 1), (1, 'Prod B', 0), (2, 'Prod B', 0), (2, 'Prod C', 0), (3, 'Prod D', 1)

SELECT DISTINCT T.Branch, T_PACK.FullDesc
    FROM @T AS T
        INNER JOIN @T AS T_PACK ON T.Branch <> T_PACK.Branch AND T_PACK.PackingLine = 1


Thank you, this however, only returned the rows that were marked as PackingLines as opposed to the ones that were not. @Bhavani answer has got me the expected result
